# Least privilege requirements for Service principal to create new key for other application

Tags: azure-active-directory

I’m currently working with a customer where we are deploying a number of Azure PaaS services via ARM templates.

The deployment runs in VSTS in service principal context.

As part of the deployment we need to specify an application ID and key for ACS.

So far we have made do with a key which was manually generated and passed to us.

We would like however to be able to generate new keys on the fly, both when applications change and to be able to do basic key management to avoid having keys expire on us.

Looking at the options though it seems as if the only way to achieve this is by setting Read and Write to all Applications in Settings/API Access/Required Permissions/AAD for the requesting Application/SSPI.

Is that really the only way or am I going about this in the wrong manner?